# How do I fix this file upload code?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, multipartform-data

I'm trying to get a very basic file upload function working and am at a complete loss to spot what I'm doing wrong. Most of the code came from SE. The way it is now all that is posted to the server is '[object FormData]', which is a text string, not an object.

The HTML form:

```
    <form id="add-torr" action="/transmission/to_client2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"class="form-inline pull-right">
        <input id="torr-files" type="file" size="30"style="color:#000; background:#ddd" multiple />
        <button id="add-torr-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

The js:

```
var form = document.getElementById('add-torr');
form.onsubmit = function(upload){
    upload.preventDefault();
    var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-torr-button');
    var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('#torr-files')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-'+i, file);
        //alert(data);
    });
    //alert($('#torr-files').val.text);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/transmission/to_client2/' + data,
        //data: data,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error in ajax form submission");
        }
    }); 
};
```

The python code:

```
#For torrent upload have to be base 64 encode
@cherrypy.expose()
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def to_client2(self, info):
    print 'info: ', info
    try:
        self.logger.info('Added torrent info to Transmission from file')
        return self.fetch('torrent-add', {'metainfo': info})
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.error('Failed to add torrent %s file to Transmission %s' % (info, e))
```

I know there are tons of examples, but I need some extra eyeballs to tell me what's wrong with my code. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

You're just adding the `FormData` object itself to the URL:

```
url: '/transmission/to_client2/' + data,
```

In JavaScript, when you add a string and some other object, it calls that object's `toString` method. Objects that don't have a `toString` method will return something like `[object MyPrototype]`.

And there's really no way around that here. You can't "pass an object" as part of a URL, because URLs are just strings. If you want to pass the form data as part of the URL, you have to encode it into a query string (as in `?key1=value1&key2=value2&…`) and add *that* to the URL.

Anyway, even if you fix that, I hope you don't expect that just adding the filenames to the query string and making a `POST` with no content is going to upload the files. You have to attach the files' content to the request in some way (e.g., as MIME multipart parts); if you never send that content, the server can never receive it.